# How do I resolve the "`Unpin` is not implemented for `from_generator..." problem when implementing a TCP concurrent connector?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I want to implement a concurrent TCP connector using Tokio. The function should initialize multiple outbound connections and only return the one that finishes the handshake first (and drop all other connections).

At first, I want to use `select!` but as far as I understand, `select!` does not apply to a vector of futures. Therefore I choose to implement a `VecSelect` structure that somehow acts as `select!(Vec<Future>)`.

My code is as follows:

```rust
use tokio::net::{TcpStream};
use std::net::SocketAddr;
use std::future::Future;
use std::pin::Pin;
use std::task::{Context, Poll};


// just a test
pub async fn my_tcp_connect(target: SocketAddr) -> std::io::Result<TcpStream> {
    let conn0 = TcpStream::connect(target);
    let conn1 = TcpStream::connect(target);
    let v = vec![conn0, conn1];
    VecSelect {
        futs: v,
    }.await
}

struct VecSelect<T: Future + Unpin> {
    futs: Vec<T>,
}

impl<T: Future + Unpin> Future for VecSelect<T> {
    type Output = T::Output;

    fn poll(mut self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        // check all futures
        for mut fut in self.futs.iter_mut() {
            if let Poll::Ready(val) = Pin::new(&mut fut).poll(cx) {
                return Poll::Ready(val);
            }
        }
       
        Poll::Pending
    }
}
```

And the following are the errors reported:

```
error[E0277]: `from_generator::GenFuture<[static generator@tokio::net::TcpStream::connect<std::net::SocketAddr>::{closure#0}]>` cannot be unpinned
   --> src/tcp_connector.rs:13:5
    |
13  |     VecSelect {
    |     ^^^^^^^^^ within `impl Future<Output = Result<tokio::net::TcpStream, std::io::Error>>`, the trait `Unpin` is not implemented for `from_generator::GenFuture<[static generator@tokio::net::TcpStream::connect<std::net::SocketAddr>::{closure#0}]>`
    |
   ::: /usr/local/cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-1.17.0/src/net/tcp/stream.rs:111:56
    |
111 |     pub async fn connect<A: ToSocketAddrs>(addr: A) -> io::Result<TcpStream> {
    |                                                        --------------------- within this `impl Future<Output = Result<tokio::net::TcpStream, std::io::Error>>`
    |
    = note: consider using `Box::pin`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `impl Future<Output = [async output]>`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `impl Future<Output = Result<tokio::net::TcpStream, std::io::Error>>`
note: required by a bound in `VecSelect`
   --> src/tcp_connector.rs:18:30
    |
18  | struct VecSelect<T: Future + Unpin> {
    |                              ^^^^^ required by this bound in `VecSelect`

error[E0277]: `from_generator::GenFuture<[static generator@tokio::net::TcpStream::connect<std::net::SocketAddr>::{closure#0}]>` cannot be unpinned
   --> src/tcp_connector.rs:13:5
    |
13  | /     VecSelect {
14  | |         futs: v,
15  | |     }.await
    | |_____^ within `impl Future<Output = Result<tokio::net::TcpStream, std::io::Error>>`, the trait `Unpin` is not implemented for `from_generator::GenFuture<[static generator@tokio::net::TcpStream::connect<std::net::SocketAddr>::{closure#0}]>`
    |
   ::: /usr/local/cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-1.17.0/src/net/tcp/stream.rs:111:56
    |
111 |       pub async fn connect<A: ToSocketAddrs>(addr: A) -> io::Result<TcpStream> {
    |                                                          --------------------- within this `impl Future<Output = Result<tokio::net::TcpStream, std::io::Error>>`
    |
    = note: consider using `Box::pin`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `impl Future<Output = [async output]>`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `impl Future<Output = Result<tokio::net::TcpStream, std::io::Error>>`
note: required by a bound in `VecSelect`
   --> src/tcp_connector.rs:18:30
    |
18  | struct VecSelect<T: Future + Unpin> {
    |                              ^^^^^ required by this bound in `VecSelect`

error[E0277]: `from_generator::GenFuture<[static generator@tokio::net::TcpStream::connect<std::net::SocketAddr>::{closure#0}]>` cannot be unpinned
   --> src/tcp_connector.rs:15:6
    |
15  |     }.await
    |      ^^^^^^ within `impl Future<Output = Result<tokio::net::TcpStream, std::io::Error>>`, the trait `Unpin` is not implemented for `from_generator::GenFuture<[static generator@tokio::net::TcpStream::connect<std::net::SocketAddr>::{closure#0}]>`
    |
   ::: /usr/local/cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-1.17.0/src/net/tcp/stream.rs:111:56
    |
111 |     pub async fn connect<A: ToSocketAddrs>(addr: A) -> io::Result<TcpStream> {
    |                                                        --------------------- within this `impl Future<Output = Result<tokio::net::TcpStream, std::io::Error>>`
    |
    = note: consider using `Box::pin`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `impl Future<Output = [async output]>`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `impl Future<Output = Result<tokio::net::TcpStream, std::io::Error>>`
note: required by a bound in `VecSelect`
   --> src/tcp_connector.rs:18:30
    |
18  | struct VecSelect<T: Future + Unpin> {
    |                              ^^^^^ required by this bound in `VecSelect`
```

As I'm new to Rust and async programming, I'm not sure if my approach is in general correct.

And I'm wondering whether `Unpin` is necessary for my implementation and why cannot the compiler derive `Unpin` automatically?

Comment: You probably want to use [`select_all`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/future/fn.select_all.html)

Comment: @Jmb thanks, seems to be exactly what I want.

Comment: Update: I later used `select_ok` function, which saves me many codes. However, I got the same problem with `Unpin`. I finally solved the problem by wrapping `Result<TcpStream>` type with a `Box::Pin()`. (Though I cannot explain why roughly I can understand the reason.)